# How can I execute java script code in c# winforms to download files?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

This is the java script code in the class JavaScript when I'm using this code in my website pressing f12 open dev tools and put the code in the console window it's working fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Downloader
{
    public class JavaScript
    {
        public string GetJavaScriptCode()
        {
            return @"const c = 'ef7eb018-7cf3-4ae1-99ac-bab1c2c5d419'
const bearer = localStorage.access_token

const getAnimationList = (page) => {
    console.log('getAnimationList page=', page);
    const init = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`,
            'X-Api-Key': 'mi'
        }
    };

    const listUrl = `some site?page=${page}&limit=96&order=&type=Motion%2CMotionPack&query=`;
    return fetch(listUrl, init).then((res) => res.json()).then((json) => json).catch(() => Promise.reject('Failed to download animation list'))
}

// retrieves json.details.gms_hash 
const getProduct = (animId, character) => {
    console.log('getProduct animId=', animId, ' character=', character);
    const init = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`,
            'X-Api-Key': 'mi'
        }
    };

    const productUrl = `some site}?similar=0&character_id=${character}`;
    return fetch(productUrl, init).then((res) => res.json()).then((json) => json).catch(() => Promise.reject('Failed to download product details'))
}

const downloadAnimation = (animId, character, product_name) => {
    console.log('downloadAnimation animId=', animId, ' character=', character, ' prod name=', product_name);
    // skip packs
    if (product_name.indexOf(',') > -1) {
        console.log('Skipping pack ', product_name);
        return Promise.resolve('Skip pack!');
    } else {
        return getProduct(animId, character)
                .then((json) => json.details.gms_hash)
                .then((gms_hash) => {
                    const pvals = gms_hash.params.map((param) => param[1]).join(',')
                    const _gms_hash = Object.assign({}, gms_hash, { params: pvals }) // Anim is baked with default param values
                    return exportAnimation(character, [_gms_hash], product_name)
                })
                .then((json) => monitorAnimation(character))
                .catch(() => Promise.reject(""Unable to download animation "" + animId))
    }
}

const downloadAnimLoop = (o) => {
    console.log('downloadAnimLoop');
    if (!o.anims.length) {
        return downloadAnimsInPage(o.currentPage + 1, o.totPages, o.character); // no anims left, get a new page
    }

    const head = o.anims[0];
    const tail = o.anims.slice(1);
    o.anims = tail;

    return downloadAnimation(head.id, o, head)
        .then(() => downloadAnimLoop(o)) //loop
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(""Recovering from animation failed to downlaod"");
            return downloadAnimLoop(o) // keep on looping 
        })
}

var downloadAnimsInPage = (page, totPages, character) => {
    console.log('downloadAnimsInPage page=', page, ' totPages', totPages, ' character=', character);
    if (page >= totPages) {
        console.log('All pages have been downloaded');
        return Promise.resolve('All pages have been downlaoded');
    }

    return getAnimationList(page)
        .then((json) => (
            {
                anims: json.results,
                currentPage: json.pagination.page,
                totPages: json.pagination.num_pages,
                character
            }))
        .then((o) => downloadAnimLoop(o))
        .catch((e) => Promise.reject(""Unable to download all animations error "", e))
}

const start = () => {
    console.log('start');
    if (!character) {
        console.error(""Please add a valid character ID at the beginnig of the script"");
        return
    }
    downloadAnimsInPage(1, 100, c);
}

const exportAnimation = (character_id, gmsHashArray, product_name) => {
    console.log('Exporting Anim´:' + character_id + "" to file:"" + product_name)
    const exportUrl = 'some site'
    const exportBody = {
        character_id,
        gms_hash: gmsHashArray, //[{ ""model-id"": 103120902, ""mirror"": false, ""trim"": [0, 100], ""overdrive"": 0, ""params"": ""0,0,0"", ""arm-space"": 0, ""inplace"": false }],
        preferences: { format: ""fbx7"", skin: ""false"", fps: ""30"", reducekf: ""0"" }, // To download collada use format: ""dae""
        product_name,
        type: ""Motion""
    };
    const exportInit = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`,
            'X-Api-Key': 'my1',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(exportBody)
    }
    return fetch(exportUrl, exportInit).then((res) => res.json()).then((json) => json)
}

const monitorAnimation = (characterId) => {
    const monitorUrl = `some site/api/v1/c/${Id}/monitor`;
    const monitorInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`,
            'X-Api-Key': 'my1'
        }
    };
    return fetch(monitorUrl, monitorInit)
        .then((res) => {
            switch (res.status) {
                case 404: {
                    const errorMsg = ('ERROR: Monitor got 404 error: ' + res.error + ' message=' + res.message);
                    console.error(errorMsg);
                    throw new Error(errorMsg);
                } break
                case 202:
                case 200: {
                    return res.json()
                } break
                default:
                    throw new Error('Response not handled', res);
            }
        }).then((msg) => {
            switch (msg.status) {
                case 'completed':
                    console.log('Downloading: ', msg.job_result);
                    downloadingTab.location.href = msg.job_result;
                    return msg.job_result;
                    break;
                case 'processing':
                    console.log('Animation is processing... looping');
                    return monitorAnimation(characterId);
                    break;// loop
                case 'failed':
                default:
                    const errorMsg = ('ERROR: Monitor status:' + msg.status + ' message:' + msg.message + 'result:' + JSON.stringify(msg.job_result));
                    console.error(errorMsg);
                    throw new Error(errorMsg);
            }
        }).catch((e) => Promise.reject(""Unable to monitor job for character "" + characterId + e))
}

start()";
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want to use it and execute it in c# winforms to download the files to specific folder.
I tried in form1 this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;

namespace Downloader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebView2 webView;
        private JavaScript javaScript;
        private string downloadFolder;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeWebView2();
            javaScript = new JavaScript();
            downloadFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MixamoAnimations");
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        }

        private void InitializeWebView2()
        {
            webView = new WebView2();
            webView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            this.Controls.Add(webView);
        }

        private void WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsSuccess)
            {
                webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived;

                webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += (s, args) =>
                {
                    webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson("{ action: 'initialize' }");
                };
            }
        }

        private async void CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = e.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                // Handle the message received from JavaScript
                if (message == "startDownload")
                {
                    await RetrieveAndDownloadAnimations();
                }
            }
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (webView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle == "Complete")
            {
                // Document is ready, send the initialization message
                webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson("{ action: 'initialize' }");

                // Remove the event handler
                webView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged -= CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged;
            }
        }

        private async Task RetrieveAndDownloadAnimations()
        {
            string[] animationNames = await RetrieveAnimations();

            // Start downloading each animation
            foreach (string animationName in animationNames)
            {
                await DownloadAnimation(animationName);
            }

            // All animations downloaded
            MessageBox.Show("Download completed.");
        }

        private async Task<string[]> RetrieveAnimations()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string apiUrl = "some site";
                    string jsonData = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(apiUrl);

                    // Parse the JSON response to retrieve animation names
                    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);
                    var animations = data.results;

                    string[] animationNames = new string[animations.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < animations.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string name = animations[i].name;
                        animationNames[i] = name;
                    }

                    return animationNames;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve animations: {ex.Message}");
                return new string[0]; // Return an empty array on error
            }
        }

        private async Task DownloadAnimation(string animationName)
        {
            try
            {
                string sanitizedFileName = SanitizeFileName(animationName);
                string fbxUrl = $"some site/{animationName}/download";

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, $"{sanitizedFileName}.fbx");
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(fbxUrl), filePath);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {sanitizedFileName}.fbx");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to download animation {animationName}: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private string SanitizeFileName(string fileName)
        {
            var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
            var sanitizedFileName = string.Join("_", fileName.Split(invalidChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            return sanitizedFileName.Trim();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Trigger the animation downloading process in JavaScript
            webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson("{ action: 'startDownload' }");
        }
    }
}
```

but it's never pass the lines

```
webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += (s, args) =>
                {
                    webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson("{ action: 'initialize' }");
                };
```

it's not throwing any errors or exceptions.

I tried before with regular webbrowser control in winforms but it didn't work either.
I want to simulate the dev tools console window operation automatic in the winforms.

I tried the above and expected it to download the files.

Comment: You've tagged _webview_. However, _WebView_ is the predecessor to _WebView2_ and isn't the same thing.